# react-select hidden input not posting

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-select

When submitting a form after on an onChange() event, the generated hidden-input does not post.

```
var requireScript = require('../data/filter');

const CategoryFilter = React.createClass({

    ...

    onChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            value: value,
        });

        //This is where I submit the form via AJAX
        requireScript.getOptions(this);
    },

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                <Creatable
                    name={this.props.fieldName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    ...

});
```

The Ajax script is totally fine and submits without error. The only problem is that the hidden input that is generated by react-select does not post.

To me, it looks as though the hidden input is only inserted into the DOM after my form is submitted. Am I using the appropriate event on which to submit my form?

Comment: Please include the relevant excepts from your code and any error messages you may be getting

Comment: @PatrickHund -thanks; please see the updated question above.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the issue for your code but setState is asynchronous. So if you set state by setState and after that invoke other functions with this as parameter and try read state from parameter in your function then is mustn't  be the value you thought you set.
Try:

`onChange(value) {
        var afterSetState = function () {
                requireScript.getOptions(this);
        };

        this.setState({
            value: value,
        }, afterSetState);


    },
`